# macOS Sierra doesn't have the crispy fonts as they used to be in earlier versions

Tags: macos, terminal, font

First, running the following command:

```
defaults -currentHost read -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing
```

gives me back `3`.

But the fonts nowhere look the way they used to look in earlier versions of macOS. I was using Yosemite before, and today I upgraded to Sierra. Below is the screenshot of Sublime Text editor.

[image]

They look OK in iTerm, but elsewhere - including browsers - font rendering is much worse.

So how can I make these fonts as crispy as they used to on earlier macOS/OS X versions? I guess it definitely has something to do with AppleFontSmoothing, or font anti-aliasing in general, but I have tried the many other options in this regard, that are as follows:

1. Setting `AppleFontSmoothing` with and without `currentHost` flag, and restarting the macbook each time I make a change to see the changes.
2. Ran the command `sudo atsutil databases -remove` to remove all the user installed fonts.
3. Re-installing the font that I was using to get the desired result. (Note: I was using "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono")
4. Tried to change font smoothing option for specific applications like `com.apple.terminal` but it didn't work either.

Note: [a similar question.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7273274?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Try turning on/off LCD Font Smoothing in system preferences?

Comment: Tried this as well, but no result.

Comment: On which Mac? Is it on an external display?

Comment: @pjctech It's MacBook Pro 2012, non retina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried clearing the Font caches? Kind of an odd issue- I'm not sure if this is gonna help, but worth a try. Maybe it needs and refresher ;)

`defaults -currentHost delete -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing`

`sudo atsutil databases -remove` and reboot, and maybe it needs and refresher. Its odd since it returns a `3`, but maybe something is wrong with your defaults.

Re-pply after rebooting `AppleFontSmoothing -int 3` and see if anything first without the string set, you already know that - but let keep the references for others:

`defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 3`

Comment: @Arslan: did you solved it?

Comment: no it didn't solve the problem for me. The problem still exists.

Comment: @ArslanAli: could you provide more info, maybe a screenshot and your GPU/Screen config.

Comment: would you be more specific on what kind of screenshot?

Comment: I can award you bounty as the time is running out, and we can keep discussing it here or on chat. What you say?

Comment: i don't care about the bounty- but yes, we should go to the chat

Comment: im already there but i need to bust out to work (8:30am@local time)- so ill be on and off in the chat- send you an invite to your stackoverflow account

Answer (score 0):

A way to slightly improve the sharpness of the fonts is to increase the contrast.

```
System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Increase Contrast
```

Comment: Did so, but it had not effect.

Answer (score 0):

For Sublime Text, you can add this in the global settings:

```
"font_face": "Monaco",
"font_options":
[
    "no_antialias"
],
"font_size": 13,
```

Italics will look not very good though.

Comment: The said problem is system wide.

Comment: All the solutions I've found while Googling around were application specific unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

On Sierra 10.12.2 (maybe older versions too) there's a setting that seems to have an effect on fonts, system-wide (*):

> AppleAntiAliasingThreshold

The default value is around 6 or 7. Apparently it defines the font size below which anti aliasing gets turned off. If you set a high value such as 40, all fonts smaller than 40 pts will not be antialiased, hence have sharp edges. This setting seems to affect multiple applications:

- TextEdit
- Eclipse (Java application)
- Some GTK applications (git gui, gitk)
- Maybe more!

**Open a Terminal and type:**

```
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleAntiAliasingThreshold -int 40
```

**This will turn off aliasing for font rendering in many text editors.**

You can delete this setting to revert to default.

Rather than setting a global preference, you can restrict it to some applications too (not tested by me) :

```
defaults write org.eclipse.eclipse AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 40
```

*(*) Note: some applications have settings that may override this setting (e.g. Terminal has a Font "antialias" setting, Sublime Text has this "font_options" preference, ...)*